# Как правильно прописать настройки в /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Tags: apache, .htaccess

На одном айпи висит несколько сайтов. Задача такая: нужно с любого несуществующего поддомена (123123.site1.com, или qwe111.site2.com, или *.site3.com) сделать редирект 301 на основной домен нужного сайта.

111.site1.com - приводит на site1.com
222.site1.com - приводит на site1.com
111.site2.com - приводит на site2.com
33dsd.site2.com - приводит на site2.com и так далее.

Сейчас если задать несуществующий субдомен мы попадаем на дефолтные настройки и ошибка 404 (htaccess в этом случае не читается - AllowOverride None). Если поставить AllowOverride All поможет это в определении домена-цели куда надо попасть?

Как это сделать и что переделать в настройках чтобы не возникло проблем в работе сайтов?

Default:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:81>
> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
> <Directory />
>     Options +FollowSymLinks Indexes
>     AllowOverride None
> </Directory>
> <Directory /var/www/>
>     Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride None
>     Order allow,deny
>     allow from all
> </Directory>
>
> ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
> <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
>     AllowOverride None
>     Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
>
> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>
> # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
> # alert, emerg.
> LogLevel warn
>
> CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

В файле apache2.conf заданы уже индивидуальные настройки по каждому сайту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я бы предложил как предпочтительный (с моей точки зрения) такой вариант:

в каждом *virtualhost-е* сделать такие примерно записи:

```
servername host1.ru
serveralias *.host1.ru

rewrite engine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^host1\.ru$ [NC]
rewriterule (.*) http://host1.ru/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

---

но можно попробовать сделать именно так, как вы спрашиваете (работоспособность не проверял).

создать «глобальный» *virtualhost* с такими примерно записями в нём:

```
servername non.exist.ent
serveralias *.host1.ru *.host2.ru *.host3.ru

rewrite engine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.([a-z0-9-]+)\.([a-z0-9-]+)$ [NC]
rewriterule (.*) %2.%3/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: rewritecond & rewriterule у вас неверные - с ними не работает. "глобальный" вариант у меня запустить не получилось, реализовал локальный под каждый отдельный домен. спасибо за наводку!

Comment: да, возможно, что я допустил ошибку (так как работоспособность не проверял). если сможете её обнаружить — смело вносите изменения в мой ответ — здесь такая практика.

Answer (score 0):

незнаю подойдет ли вам. Я предлагаю вам создать виртуальный хост ([линк](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-ubuntu-14-04-lts-ru))

В инструкции есть настройки под виртуальный хост, обратите внимание на serveralias

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

в алиасах и задайте им псевдонимы какие нужны.